# Difference between Yognidra and Meditation

Tags: meditation, yog-nidra

What are difference between [Yognidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_nidra) and [Meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation)?

or

Is Yognidra form of meditation?